# Change the owner account id of a file in iOS

Tags: ios, uikit

I see that there is a NSFileOwnerAccountName attribute. But I get an error if I try to set it on a folder that I created. Is it possible to transfer ownership of a folder in iOS (something like chown)?

Comment: you can use NSFileManager class "setAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes ofItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error" method to change ownership of a folder. but you can do within NSDocumentDirectory only.

Comment: What are the possible values I could use for this key (NSFileOwnerAccountName). In other words how do I know the NSFileOwnerAccountID of valid accounts on this device?

Comment: A dictionary containing as keys the attributes to set for path and as values the corresponding value for the attribute. You can set the following attributes: NSFileBusy, NSFileCreationDate, NSFileExtensionHidden, NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID, NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName, NSFileHFSCreatorCode, NSFileHFSTypeCode, NSFileImmutable, NSFileModificationDate, NSFileOwnerAccountID, NSFileOwnerAccountName, NSFilePosixPermissions. You can change single attributes or any combination of attributes; you need not specify keys for all attributes.

Comment: NSFileManager contains method to get and set values.